# Редактирование файла app.config во время выполнения программы

Tags: c#, .net

Я добавил в программу Settings с именем lastRun и типом string и Value="NoRun".

Подскажите, есть ли в C# штатные средства, с помощью которых я могу редактировать Value в файле App.config?

Т.е допустим во время выполнения программы, я присваиваю настройке lastRun="Success".

А при следующем запуске программы, я считываю lastRun, а в нем находится значение Success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А зачем вам редактировать app.config? Присвойте новое значение в `lastRun` и запишите Settings.

Не забывайте, что ваше значение должно быть в пользовательских параметрах, а не параметрах приложения (ясно, почему?)

Обычно это выглядит как

```
Properties.Settings.Default.lastRun = "Success";
```

и после этого (немедленно или в конце программы, как вам кажется правильнее)

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

[Документация на MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb397755%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Можно пример, при котором при следующем запуске программы я получу новое значение lastRun?

Comment: @iluxa1810: Ну, поменяйте значение `lastRun`, выполните `Save` и перезапустите программу.

Comment: @iluxa1810: Может, вы положили свойство в параметры приложения, а не пользовательские? Иначе должно работать.

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Такой вопрос, а куда сохраняются пользовательские настройки? Я думал, что при сохранении настроек будет правиться app.config (Т.е правиться value в узле lastRun).

Comment: @iluxa1810: Данные кладутся в `%APPDATA%\<имя приложения>\...`, т. к. это место, доступное для записи текущему пользователю. В нормальных условиях приложение инсталлируется в `%PROGRAMFILES%`, бежит от имени пользователя, и таким образом не может менять файлы в каталоге, откуда запущено.

Comment: А если программа запускается первый раз на ПК пользователя, то настройки берутся, те, которые я задал при создании setting lastRun?

Comment: @iluxa1810: Угу, именно так.